# Do I need to define a module for each separate file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to Angular, trying to figure out how I should [modularize](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/27/13-step-guide-angularjs-modularization/) my app.

```
app
    toolbar
        toolbar.module.js
        menu.html
        index.html
        search.html
    sub-system-1
        subSystem1.module.js
        directive-template.html
    sub-system-2
        subSystem2.module.js
        directive-template.html
```

The toolbar.module.js for example has 3 directives (menu, index, search) and each directive has its own controller, service.  All the controllers, directive definitions and services are defined in the toolbar.module.js...kind of confusing when it comes to maintaining the code.

Is it possible to come up with a finer grained setup such that each directive is enclosed in its own file along side its controller & service?

I figure I could add:

```
        menu.directive.js
```

And inside there have something like

```
var module = angular('toolbar.menu.directive',[]);
module.directives(...);//add menu directive to the module
```

Then inside toolbar.modules have something like:

```
var module = angular('toolbar',[toolbar.menu.directive]);
```

Is this the only way I can achieve this by defining lots of fine-grained modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to define tons of tiny modules. In Angular, you can reference an existing module by omitting the second argument:

```
angular.module('moduleName');
```

By doing this, you can split your various toolbar directives, controllers, and services into separate files and in each file simply reference the toolbar module like so:

```
angular.module('toolbar')
  .controller('MenuCtrl', function() {
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: You've just got to make sure that they get run in the right order. If `angular.module('moduleName');` gets run before `angular.module('moduleName', []);` then you'll get an error.